# Evolución del significado de "porquezuela"

Tags: etimología, significado, historia, dle, animales

Según el [NTLLE](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle), la palabra **porquezuela** aparece únicamente en los diccionarios de Minsheu (1617), Franciosini (1620), Academia (1803, 1817 y 1822) y de Nuñez de Taboada (1825) como:

> s.f.d. de PUERCA

que interpreto como "sustantivo femenino ¿despectivo? ¿diminutivo?" de puerca.

La palabra parece haber desaparecido de los diccionarios hasta la edición de [1992 del Diccionario de la lengua](https://webfrl.rae.es/ntllet/SrvltGUILoginNtlletPub), donde reaparece con la acepción que se mantiene [hoy día](https://dle.rae.es/porquezuela?):

> f. desus. tuerca.

Ese cambio me parece realmente sorprendente: una forma despectiva (o diminutiva) de **puerca** (un animal) desaparece del diccionario y reaparece en los diccionarios 170 años después como **desus.** y referido a una **tuerca** (una pieza de metal).

¿Hay alguna razón conocida para este curioso fenómeno?

Comment: Es posible que "s.f.d." signifique "sustantivo femenino diminutivo".

Comment: @Charlie: efectivamente, podría ser diminutivo  -> edito.

Answer (score 1):

Pues parece que *porquezuela* como componente de máquinas ya se utilizaba en el año 1582. Buscando en el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html), encontramos en la "Traducción de la Arquitectura de Marco Vitruvio Pollión", de Miguel de Urrea (1582), los siguientes extractos:

> Alrededor de la rodaxa baxe una soga de lo alto y buelva a la **porquezuela** que está en lo baxo de la máchina, y átese allí, y la **porquezuela** se meneará constreñida con las barras y levantará por sí la máchina sin que aya peligro.

> Súcula: **porquezuela** de máchinas, su gruesso se dize camilo o bolsa, pónese asida en los chelonios, que son las sortijas como ombligos en que se rebuelve con su exe. Tiene un tímpano o rueda ancha que dizen peritrochión.

(parece ser que una [súcula](https://dle.rae.es/s%C3%BAcula) es actualmente un torno, o "máquina que consiste en un cilindro dispuesto para girar").

En "Fábrica y uso de varios instrumentos matemáticos", de José Zaragoza (1675), encontramos

> Porque el triángulo no puede inmediatamente afirmarse en la vara, se ha hecho el cañón EF. (Fig. 50.) de bronze con el clavo E. que entra en el agujero x. del triángulo (Fig. 47.) y se le añade su **porquezuela**, para más seguridad, y el tornillo F. (Fig. 50.) para tener inmoble el cañón EF.

En la Hemeroteca Digital de la BNE, encontramos un caso más en la [edición de "El Obrero Gráfico" de 23/4/1916, n.º 50, página 11](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0029870732&page=11&search=porquezuela&lang=es):

> [...] y dícese rama. Esta tiene ciertas  concavidades  por los dos lados, y el pie en que encajan,  de metal, cobre o  hie­rro, ciertos  pedazos  que llenan  aquellos  vacíos,  lla­mándolos porquezuelas.

Estos son **todos** los ejemplos que hay en el CREA y en el CORDE de *porquezuela* con un significado relacionado con máquinas. Parece por tanto que es un término extremadamente poco común, pero ya existía en 1582.

Comment: Los ejemplos que recoge indican que **porquezuela** tenía antaño un significado relacionado con las máquinas. Pero las definiciones recogidas en los diccionarios antiguos lo relacionan con **puerca**. En ese sentido en el CORDE hay ejemplos de porquezuela/porquezuelo con ese significado, como "... á cuestas traíamos, y dos porquezuelas, y un cochinillo, y una polla, y un pollo..." (Carta de Pedro de Valdivia á S. M., Cárlos V, dándole noticia de la conquista de Chile... 1545), o "... Elicia, avnque la porquezuela dixo que auía dos ..." (1536: Tercera parte de la tragicomedia de Celestina)